# Run linux command as a root user using php

Tags: php, linux

I have CENTOS Server
And i have firewall in this server. This server can send or received only allowed IP data.
I want to allow IP in iptables with Linux command as a root user using PHP.
I know the the command.  just i need, how to i can do this using PHP?

Comment: It's not good thing at all.It's secure mess

Comment: You should take a look at the `sudo` command (read its manual page: `man sudo` and `man sudoers`) and also the corresponsing php extension. But as already mentioned: from a security point of view this is questionable. You really have to take care not open security holes that way.

Comment: you can use php exec() function to execute the same command you use to enter ip in iptables. But its not secure specially if it is executing command from external source.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308793/run-linux-command-as-a-root-user-usinh-php